# Using d3.behavior.drag, How to keep a drag image visible outside of the svg element

Tags: d3.js

Using `d3.behavior.drag()`, is there a way to enable a dragged image to be visible outside of its parent `svg` element borders.

In my app, I have a top layout based on an HTML grid (using flexBox) and several D3.js graphs located in each grid cell. Each graph is built with an SVG element and its childrens.

I need a drag and drop feature to enable copy/move of elements between these graphs. As now, the feature is working except that the drag image disappears  when I cross the border of the source graph.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

    svg {
        float: left;
        border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
        border-right: solid 1px #ccc;
        margin-right: -1px;
        margin-bottom: -1px;
    }

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var width = 240,
            height = 125,
            radius = 20;

    var overSVG;

    var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
            .origin(function (d) {
                return d;
            })
            .on("drag", dragmove)
            .on("dragend", dragend);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("div").selectAll("svg")
            .data(d3.range(2).map(function (v, i) {
                return {
                    svgElement: i,
                    x    : width / 2,
                    y    : height / 2
                };
            }))
            .enter().append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("id", function (d, i) {
                return "svg_" + i
            })
            .on("mouseover", over)
            .on("mouseout", out);

    svg.append("circle")
            .attr("r", radius)
            .attr("cx", function (d) {
                return d.x;
            })
            .attr("cy", function (d) {
                return d.y;
            })
            .attr("svgElement", function (d, i) {
                return i;
            })
            .call(drag);

    function over(d, i) {
        overSVG = d;
        var selectedNodeId = "#svg_" + i;
        d3.select(selectedNodeId)
                .attr("fill", 'red');
    }
    function out(d, i) {
        overSVG = "";
        var selectedNodeId = "#svg_" + i;
        d3.select(selectedNodeId)
                .attr("fill", 'blue');
    }

    function dragmove(d) {
        d3.select(this)
                .attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x)
                .attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);

        console.log("drag move", this, d3.event.x, ' ', d3.event.y);
    }
    function dragend(d) {
        console.log("==>drag Ended :");
        console.log("   dragged circle", this);
        console.log("   from svg ", d);
        console.log("   to",  overSVG);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are after without any code. You should provide at least some relevant parts of your code or, even better, provide a live demo.

Comment: There is some code now. Regrads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the `svg` elements have an `overflow` attribute set to `hidden`.
You can try setting the `overflow` attribute to `visible`

```
svg {
   overflow: visible;
}
```

Again, without seeing a working example, it's hard to tell if this will work for you, but maybe it can help.

Comment: Dear Cloud;)  Thanks for the answer but it does'nt work for me. Will prepare some code to illustrate...

Comment: @jean-pierrelougrat When putting this in your code, it works for me. You are then able to drag the circles across the borders and outside of their viewport.

Comment: If that works, you can mark the answer as correct. This will help others that have a similar issue. Regards!

Comment: Yes it works for me too. But I have still a problem of having the dragged image either over or under the other circle. In my real app, the numbers of graphs and dragged items is much more important so  it seems too complex to reorder the items as appropriate to the dragged object. Would need to have the dragged image cloned as the last children of the html.body as mentioned in http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/custom-drag-image.html ???   Merci! merci!

Comment: Have you tried setting a higher z-index for the dragged image? Try this css rule: div.dragged-image {z-index: 1000;}

Comment: At the risk of asking the obvious: Did you replace div.dragged-image with your own selector for the dragged element?

Comment: Yes now :-) with circle.dragged-image {z-index:1000}. Not working. Not sure there is a z-index for svg elements...  Plus I don't see how I could deal with this approach in my app , because I have several dragged images in several distinct graphs. I would need and id as a selector...